# Is it possible to optimize my setInterval function a bit?

Tags: jquery, performance

I have made this simple slider with jQuery and CSS.

https://jsfiddle.net/v39qch7o/2/

```js
var ticker = 0;
var domElement = $('.ticker__item');

window.setInterval(function() {
  ticker = ticker + 1;
  $(domElement).removeClass('active');
  //  console.log(ticker);

  if (ticker == 1) {
    $('.div-1').addClass('active');
  }
  if (ticker == 2) {
    $('.div-2').addClass('active');

  }
  if (ticker == 3) {
    $('.div-3').addClass('active');
    ticker = 0;
  }
}, 2000);
```

```css
.ticker__item {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s ease;
}
.div-1 {
  background: pink;
}
.div-2 {
  background: green;
}
.div-3 {
  background: brown;
}
.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ticker">
  <div class="ticker__item div-1">Hello world 1</div>
  <div class="ticker__item div-2">Hello world 2</div>
  <div class="ticker__item div-3">Hello world 3</div>
</div>
```

I'm wondering if is an OK way to make a simple slide show. Will it be OK to run this code when my users are on a phone, and they have scrolled pass these divs. Will it make their devices work to hard and drain their batteries?

I just want to make nice, simple code. Please review my code and tell me if I could do it in an more performance friendly manner :-)

Comment: If the code works and you are looking for it to be optimized, please ask on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: try to make this only when the slie is in window, and stop it when is scroll it out from window

Comment: Your `domElement` is already a jQuery object so no need to do `$(domElement)` and why no just append ticker to your selector: `$('.div-' + ticker)`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about reviewing a code that is working perfectly fine. OP should consider asking on CodeReview instead.

Comment: For code review and performance your not on the right site.... Take a look here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry for posting in the wrong place. I didn't know that there was a "codereview"-website :-)

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón I was thinking the same thing, but won't a scroll event listener also have an impact on the performance?

Answer (score 1):

You can use modulo math and just concat the ticker variable:

```
window.setInterval(
function () {
    domElement.removeClass('active');
    $('.div-' + (++ticker)).addClass('active');
    ticker = ticker % 3
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and simplifying my code :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for performance, you should try to have a unique selector.

`$(domElement).removeClass('active');` This will loop and remove class from all divs, but only 1 div has the necessary class, so you have `n-1` iterations that will have no effect.

Instead, try `$('.ticker__item.active');`.

Also, having a count variable and `div-1 ... div-3` looks like an overhead. You can just use generic classes and check for next sibling and add class to it. If you do not have next sibling, jump to first sibling and restart the process again.

This removes any dependency on counter variable(`ticker`) and removes 1 unwanted global variable. This also makes your function generic and if you wish to add more ticker, you just have to add valid markup.

```js
window.setInterval(function() {
  var nextDiv = $('.ticker__item.active')
    .removeClass('active')
    .next('.ticker__item');
  var firstDiv = $('.ticker__item:first');
  (nextDiv.length ? nextDiv : firstDiv).addClass('active'); 
}, 2000);
```

```css
.ticker__item {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s ease;
}
.div-1 {
  background: pink;
}
.div-2 {
  background: green;
}
.div-3 {
  background: brown;
}
.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ticker">
  <div class="ticker__item div-1">Hello world 1</div>
  <div class="ticker__item div-2">Hello world 2</div>
  <div class="ticker__item div-3">Hello world 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see. Yes, that is a nice way to do it. I think that I wanted to do something like this in the first place, but my JS skills aren't quite there yet. But it looks so obvious once you see the correct solution. If you dont mind, I will copy/paste your code :-)

Comment: Thanks. I do understand it. It was a great help for me @Rajesh

Comment: @Fusentast Glad I was able to help!